# ASP.Net MVC Futures Refresh For MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-futures

With the release of MVC2, what noteworthy features are included in the refresh of the MVC Futures library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two versions of MVC Futures that sit alongside MVC 2 RTM.  One version targets .NET 3.5; the other targets .NET 4.  (The .NET 4 version is not a superset of the .NET 3.5 version; you must include both of them in your application if you want the entire range of functionality.)  Download from http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742.

A non-exhaustive feature list (.NET 3.5+):

- A **diagnostics page** which can help diagnose runtime and assembly loading errors (see [documentation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/diagnosing-aspnet-mvc-problems.html)).
- A new, **more powerful model binding and validation system**.  Detailed documentation and a tutorial are available at the above link.
- Improved support for building **RESTful services** (see the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Resources namespace).
- Strongly-typed **ActionLink<T>()**.
- A slew of **other filters and helpers**, such as Html.Serialize() (see [blog post](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/10/08/Leveraging-ASPNET-MVC-2-futures-ViewState.aspx)), Html.Script(), etc.
- A slew of **other value providers**, such as JsonValueProviderFactory.
- The ability to **turn off Session State** for individual controllers to increase parallelism in your site (see [documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/rickandy/archive/2009/12/17/session-less-mvc-controller.aspx)).

The version of MVC Futures that targets ASP.NET 4 additionally includes:

- The ability to have **partial output caching**, e.g. caching the result of a RenderAction() separately from the rest of the page.
- **DynamicViewPage** allows you to use real dynamic objects in your ViewPage, somewhat more full-featured than the default ViewPage<dynamic>.
- The ability to use **DataAnnotations 4 attributes**.
- **Remote validation**, **IClientValidatable** (the ability of a validation attribute to supply its own client validation info), and the ability for custom non-DataAnnotations attributes to contribute to ModelMetadata information.

Answer (score 0):

A great overview of MVC3 Futures is available here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/26/using-the-features-of-asp-net-mvc-3-futures.aspx